# Mi base de datos registra todos los valores en 0 cuando hago un Post desde fetch. Node.js mySql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos

Aquí tengo el código del backend:

```
router.post('/usuario', (req,res)=>{
 const {Id_document, Email, Password} = req.body;
 let usuario = {Id_document, Email, Password};
 let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES (Id_document, Email, Password)`; 
 mysqlConnection.query(newUser, usuario, (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err.message);
   }
   res.json({ message: req.body, })
   });
 });
```

**Tambien he probado reemplazar el VALUES por ?**

```
 router.post('/usuario', (req,res)=>{
 const {Id_document, Email, Password} = req.body;
 let usuario = {Id_document, Email, Password};
 let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES (?)`; 
 mysqlConnection.query(newUser, usuario, (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err.message);
   }
   res.json({ message: req.body, })
   });
 });
```

**Los valores que registra la base datos son 0:**

```
 {
    "Id_document": 0,
    "Email": "0",
    "Password": 0
  },
```

Ayuda, no sé que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES ("` + user.Id_document + `", "` + user.Email + `", "` + user.Password + `")`;
```

**Necesita crear una cadena de consulta completa. Añadiendo los valores del usuario en la cadena de consulta.**